# Cypress перестает выполнять тест при смене фокуса на любое другое окно в chrome

Tags: google-chrome, cypress

С недавних пор при запуске cypress тестов перестает выполняться код с момента клика на любое другое окно в chrome. При работе с другим браузерами таких проблем нет. Пытался поиграться с настройками браузера, переустанавливал, ставил более старую версию - безуспешно.

Раньше все было ок, подскажите пожалуйста как решить эту проблему.

```
const { defineConfig } = require('cypress')

module.exports = defineConfig({
viewportHeight: 1080,
viewportWidth: 1920,
redirectionLimit: 100,
chromeWebSecurity: false,
reporter: 'mocha-junit-reporter',
reporterOptions: {
mochaFile: 'results/test-results[hash].xml',
testCaseSwitchClassnameAndName: false,
}

env:...
e2e:...
```